# Eclipse Oxigen suggestion execution time

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

Can someone please advice how to solve such an issue:
Using the "alt+enter" Eclipse's (Eclipse Oxigen) feature to auto-finish + suggestions on my Java(maven, spring, javafx) project. And every time it is taking 2-3 seconds, which is becoming a pain.

I cannot say that this is due to PC's slowness(i5, ssd and etc.), so I'm assuming that something has changed from the side of Eclipse(at home I'm using an old favored Eclipse Luna release, and I don't recall seeing it work this slow).

I've already tried suggestions of altering the 'eclipse.ini' to give it more juice, but that didn't give anything.

---

Addition:

Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)

JDK: 
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

Comment: Please update your post with full details of your Eclipse version. You can get that from the **Help > About** window. Also specify which JDK you are using for your project. That information is relevant. For example, see this Eclipse bug for slow autocomplete with Java 9 but not Java 8 using an early release of Oxygen: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526067

Comment: Thanks. Will update(actually I am using JDK9)

Comment: OK, upgrading Eclipse sounds good. Please update your post if you continue to have problems with the latest release of Oxygen.

Comment: Will try. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the latest update fixed this.